# How to interpret the matrix representation of a quantum gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I am trying to understand how the quantum gates work, so I started with the simplest one, the [Pauli X gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Pauli-X_gate).

I get that it turns $|0\rangle$ into $|1\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$
to $|0\rangle$.

So my question is how do I read its matrix:

\begin{equation}
X = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

What maps to it?

Comment: Welcome to quantum computing SE! Does [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5989/23) look like what you want to know? If not, what's the difference between that question (and the answers) and what you're looking for?

Comment: @Mithrandir24601  Thanks for the welcoming. For starters, the question isnt exactly on my experience level! I am only now past getting the besic concepts in QC. So the question and answers are not very related to this(from my POV)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets understand this first using Bra-Ket notation then we move on to answering : what does a matrix maps by just looking at it.

Lets get some basics out of the way,
the vectors $\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\vert 1 \rangle$ are represented by,

\begin{equation}
\vert 0 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \& \ \ \  
\vert 1 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

This implies,
\begin{equation}
\vert 0 \rangle \langle 1\vert = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\ \ \ \ \ \& \ \ \  
\vert 1 \rangle \langle 0\vert = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Now, I can write my $X$ gate as,
\begin{equation}
X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \vert 0 \rangle \langle 1\vert  + \vert 1 \rangle \langle 0\vert .
\end{equation}

The term $\vert 1 \rangle \langle 0\vert$ maps $\vert 0 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 1 \rangle$, and the term $\vert 0 \rangle \langle 1\vert$ maps $\vert 0 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 1 \rangle$. You can see this by:

\begin{equation}
\left(\vert 0 \rangle \langle 1 \vert\right)  \vert 1\rangle = \vert 0 \rangle
\ \ \ \ \ \& \ \ \ 
\left(\vert 1 \rangle \langle 0 \vert\right)  \vert 0\rangle = \vert 1 \rangle.
\end{equation}

Given a matix you can always write it in this bra-ket notation, and easily see how it maps.

As you gain experience working  with these it is easy to see that a general matrix pictorially can be represented as, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a\vert 0 \rangle\langle 0 \vert & b \vert 0 \rangle\langle 1 \vert \\ c\vert 1 \rangle\langle 0 \vert & d\vert 1 \rangle\langle 1 \vert \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Note the word pictorially, cause the way I wrote it, in standard text it would imply a $4\times4$ matrix. Now given a matrix you can easily work out how each of the non-zero term acts on the basis states $\vert 0 \rangle, \vert 1 \rangle$ ans see where the matrix maps to.

For example, 
\begin{equation}
Z = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} 
has non-zero terms $\vert 0 \rangle\langle0 \vert$ which maps $\vert 0 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 0 \rangle$, and $-\vert 1 \rangle\langle1 \vert$ which maps $\vert 1 \rangle \rightarrow -\vert 1 \rangle$.

Now a homework for you, Understand the mapping of  Hadamard gate and then move on to understand $CNOT$ gate.

Note: I did not worry about what $\vert 1 \rangle \langle 0\vert$ maps $\vert 1 \rangle$ to, cause of orthogonality.

**EDIT : After writing this I realized maybe you are asking the following**

Lets say someone gives you a mapping and ask you to find the matrix that applies the said mapping. Note that
$$
\vert x \rangle \langle b \vert
$$ 
maps $\vert b \rangle $ to $\vert x \rangle$.
So as an example if one asks you find the matrix that maps 
$\vert 0 \rangle \rightarrow (\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle)/\sqrt{2}$
 and $\vert 1 \rangle \rightarrow (\vert 0 \rangle - \vert 1 \rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ you can easily write the matrix being

$$
\frac{\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\langle 0 \vert + \frac{\vert 0 \rangle - \vert 1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\langle 1 \vert
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert 0 \rangle\langle 0 \vert + \vert 0 \rangle\langle 1 \vert + \vert 1 \rangle\langle 0 \vert - \vert 1 \rangle\langle 1 \vert) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Its now pretty clear to me how it all works.
BTW, is there an typo when you wrote $d\vert 1 \rangle\langle 01 \vert$ and shouldnt that be $d\vert 1 \rangle\langle 1 \vert$ ?

Comment: You are welcome! And thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: Hi again, i thought i understood but turns out i dont. So my question is how does this happen:
\begin{equation}
\vert 0 \rangle \langle 1\vert = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\ \ \ \ \ \& \ \ \  
\vert 1 \rangle \langle 0\vert = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
how does $\vert 0 \rangle \langle 1\vert$ and $\vert 1 \rangle \langle 0\vert$map to matrix?
Thanks!

Comment: @AleksandarKostovic: If you know what column-vectors are represented by $\lvert 0 \rangle$ and $\lvert 1 \rangle$, and you know what row-vectors are represented by $\langle 0 \rvert$ and $\langle 1 \rvert$, then you should be able to see how that works by simple matrix multiplication. There is no mystery in this case --- it's all just basic matrix algebra.

Comment: Thanks! Now i get it :)